# Is it possible to access SessionId in IHttpContext.LogRequest within an IHttpModule

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

The `IHttpContext.LogRequest` event seems a natural event to handle if you want to log request using a custom IHttpModule. The problem I'm facing is that I would like to store the session id on the log, but it is not available for the majority of request when `LogRequest` is hit.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

```
public class ActivityTraceModule : IHttpModule, IRequiresSessionState, IReadOnlySessionState
{
    static Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
        context.LogRequest += OnLogRequest;
    }

    public void OnLogRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {
        var app = (HttpApplication)source;
        var context = app.Context;
        var sessionId = context.Session != null ? context.Session.SessionID : null;
        logger.Debug("SessionId: " + sessionId);
    }
}
```

It looks like session state is already released by the time `LogRequest` is hit, as this image indicates:

[image: ASP.NET App Lifecycle]

Should I use another event to do the logging? Ideally the response should already be fully available. Or is there a way to properly access session state in the `IHttpContext.LogRequest` event I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I really didn't find a way to access the request's `Session` from the `LogRequest` event, so I just subscribed to another event:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context) {
    context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += OnLogRequest;
    //context.LogRequest += OnLogRequest;
}
```

*(I know, I'm lazy, I didn't change the event handler name, but that's because I would rather have it meaning what it does than what event are attached to it :-) )*

After that I was able to access the session for every request which had an actual session.

I've encountered another "problem" though: ASP.NET reuses the session ID stored on a cookie for subsequent requests, even after the user has logged out. Since I wanted to use the session id to "group by" each user's "login session" I had to clear the session ID to force the use of a new one. To accomplish that I've created an extension method to abandon the session and clear its session id:

```
public static void AbandonAndClearSessionCookie(this HttpSessionState session) {
    session.Clear();
    session.Abandon();
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Response != null)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(new HttpCookie("ASP.NET_SessionId", ""));
}
```

Note: *This method is not foolproof and the session ID cookie name can be changed in the `web.config` file. I'll mostly certainly improve the previous code.*

Then it was a matter to use it when the user logged out:

```
protected void HeadLoginStatus_LoggingOut(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e) {
    Session.AbandonAndClearSessionCookie();
}
```

I've simply attached an event handler to the `HeadLoginStatus.LoggingOut` event.

In ASP.NET MVC I had to write it on the `AuthController.Logout` method:

```
public ActionResult Logout() {
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
    Session.AbandonAndClearSessionCookie();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```